# Running a new 240v circuit for a dryer

Tags: wiring, dryer, 240v

I just bought a home with a gas hookup for the dryer, but I have a fairly recent, perfectly working electric dryer, so I've decided to run a 240v line instead of purchasing a new gas dryer. This is what I plan to do and wanted to run it by you folks to see if it makes sense and if there are any gotchas I should be sure to look out for. (I'll also be re-reading Richter/Schwann's "Wiring Simplified" to make sure I do things correctly.)

- Dryer is rated at 240V, 30 amps. It comes configured for a 3-wire connection, but this can be changed to a 4-wire connection by separating the neutral and ground wire inside the dryer. (Instructions are provided for this in the manual.)
- I'll need to use a 4-wire connection since the circuit I'll be installing is post-1996 (per NEC)
- House has 200 amp electric service
- I'll add a 30 amp breaker to the main panel and use Romex 10/3 NM-B w/ground.
- The run from the dryer to the panel is about 50 feet or less

Any suggestions or worries about the above? Thanks.

Comment: Might want to figure out the operating costs of gas vs electric dryer first.  In some places with high electricity prices it would be cheaper in the long run to sell the used electric dryer and buy a new/used gas one.

Comment: Thanks--that was my original plan but it looks like it will take me many years to pay back the difference (between the cost of installing a 240 line and buying a decent gas dryer). Plus, I need to do something soon as the laundry is piling up in my new home. :) When this dryer dies, I'll probably buy a gas dryer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got it.

Just make sure to separate the neutral and the ground on the dryer and use a 4-wire dryer whip and receptacle.

Sounds like a plan.

Good luck!